# Override .next method of a subject via decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, service, decorator

I have got an angular application, and there i have lot of Subjects/BehaviorSubjects/ReplaySubjects as properties in several services.
I'm currently trying to create a typescript decorator i could add to some of this Subjects, in order to get some "extra" functionality when the .next function of this Subject is called (manually calling a global change-detection..)
But currently i dont get it working, as i never have access to that instances of the Subjects..

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService extends HttpService {

    @TriggerGlobalChangeDetection
    public mySubject$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}
```

content of the decorator.ts:

```
// export function TriggerGlobalChangeDetection(): (Target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
//     const origNext = Target.prototype.next;
//     Target.prototype.next = function () {
//         console.log('overriding next');
//         origNext.apply(this);
//         GlobalChangeDetectionService.detectChanges();
//     };
// };

export function TriggerGlobalChangeDetection(
    target?: any,
    propertyName?: string,
    descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor
) {
    const origNext = target.prototype.next;
    console.log('overriding next');
    origNext.apply(this);
    GlobalChangeDetectionService.detectChanges();
}

// export const TriggerGlobalChangeDetection = (Target: any, p: string): any => {
//     return class extends Target {
//         next = (value: any): void => {
//             super.next(value);
//             GlobalChangeDetectionService.detectChanges();
//         };
//     };
// };
```

As you see, i tried different implementations of the decorator... but all of them are failing because of that `Target.prototype.next` throwing an exception.
I got, that `Target` is of type `HttpService`. I guess this is why i cannot access `mySubject$`

Does anyone have an idea how to get that working what i'm trying?

Kind regards
Simon

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
export class SomeService {

  
  private _mySubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(false);

  get _mySubject(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this._mySubject$;
  }

//.... either in constructor or function etc. 
        if (some condition = true) {
          this._mySubject$.next(true);
        } else {
          this._mySubject$.next(false);
        }
```

Then you can use `SomeService._mySubject` in other components or where needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not really what i am looking for.. i need a generic way to add some additional Code being executed whenever the .next function is called on that annotated subject